# How do I filter out some rows from a dataset based on two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the [*Iris* flower data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set):

[image]

In the species, I have three different items of information:

```
 print(df['Species'].unique())
['setosa' 'versicolor' 'virginica']
```

I want to filter out all rows and all rows where `Species= 'setosa'` and `Petal.width'= 0.4`:

```
df[df['Species']!='setosa' & (df['Petal.width'] != '0.4')]
```

The problem is that this function delete all rows which contain `df['Species']=='setosa'` and all rows which contains  `df['Petal.width'] == '0.4'`.

I want to apply two conditions in the same time.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Use `df[(df['Species']!='setosa') & (df['Petal.width'] != 0.4)]`

Comment: I think you need use `df[(df['Species'] == 'setosa') & (df['Petal.width'] == 0.4)]`

Comment: @jezrael  Thank you but that is what I have already did. It does not work; It delete all lines  df['Species']!='setosa'. That is not my goal. I want to delete rows where I have  both df['Species']!='setosa') & (df['Petal.width'] != 0.4). I want to apply both conditions in the same time.

Comment: @dina - Yes, I understand. Solution in first comemnt not working?

Comment: @jezrael thank you for your answer but it does not work.

Comment: `df[(df['Species']!='setosa') & (df['Petal.width'] != '0.4')]` working ?